# ActionMailer SMTP "certificate verify failed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, smtp

I want to send emails from my Rails web application, and I do not want to disable TLS certificate verification. However for some reason, it always fails with "SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed", even though the server certificate is valid.

I doubled checked with `openssl s_client` (using `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`), and running the following in the rails console also works, delivering successfully.

```
smtp = Net::SMTP.new(host, port)
smtp.enable_tls
smtp.start("localhost", username, password, :login) do |smtp|
  smtp.send_message msgstr, from, to
end
```

The server has Rails 4.2.6 and Ruby 2.3.0

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_setting = {
    address: 
    port: 465,
    user_name: 
    password: 
    authentication: :login,
    openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER,
    enable_starttls_auto: false,
    ssl: true
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the described behavior I am quite sure that peer verification has not been done in the console and that you need to explicitly **set the certificate store for verifying peer certificates in your Rails configuration**.

#### Why it "works" in the console and how to actually verify peers there:

The observation that it works from the console but does not from Rails code is caused by the fact that `smtp.enable_tls` in your console code **does not force peer verification** whereas your Rails configuration apparently does. Indeed, when you write the command to the console, you get the `SSLContext` printed out:

```
smtp.enable_tls
# => #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext:0x000000064043d0 @cert=nil, @key=nil,
       @client_ca=nil, @ca_file=nil, @ca_path=nil, @timeout=nil,
       @verify_mode=nil, @verify_depth=nil, @renegotiation_cb=nil,
       @verify_callback=nil, @cert_store=nil, @extra_chain_cert=nil, 
       @client_cert_cb=nil, @session_id_context=nil, @tmp_dh_callback=nil, 
       @session_get_cb=nil, @session_new_cb=nil, @session_remove_cb=nil, 
       @tmp_ecdh_callback=nil, @servername_cb=nil, @npn_protocols=nil, 
       @alpn_protocols=nil, @alpn_select_cb=nil, @npn_select_cb=nil>
```

Note that `@verify_mode` is `nil` so there is no peer verification enabled by default on the `SSLContext`.

To force peer verification in console, so that you can play with the SSL settings manually, you need to use a custom `SSLContext` and pass it to `enable_tls`:

```
ssl_context = Net::SMTP.default_ssl_context
ssl_context.set_params
smtp.enable_tls(ssl_context)
# => #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext:0x000000063c27c8 @cert=nil, @key=nil, 
       @client_ca=nil, @ca_file=nil, @ca_path=nil, @timeout=nil, 
       @verify_mode=1, @verify_depth=nil, @renegotiation_cb=nil, 
       @verify_callback=nil, @cert_store=#<OpenSSL::X509::Store:0x00000002894408 @verify_callback=nil, @error=nil, @error_string=nil, @chain=nil, @time=nil>, @extra_chain_cert=nil, 
       @client_cert_cb=nil, @session_id_context=nil, @tmp_dh_callback=nil, 
       @session_get_cb=nil, @session_new_cb=nil, @session_remove_cb=nil, 
       @tmp_ecdh_callback=nil, @servername_cb=nil, @npn_protocols=nil, 
       @alpn_protocols=nil, @alpn_select_cb=nil, @npn_select_cb=nil>
```

Watch closely the differences: the `SSLContext` now has `verify_mode` set to 1 and has a certificate store for the verifications defined. This is (among other things) what the [`set_params` method](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/blob/master/lib/openssl/ssl.rb#L123) in `SSLContext` does.

#### How to configure the certificate store in Rails

Now, Rails does not call the `set_params` methods when constructing the `SSLContext` for SMTP connection. Instead, it sets the individual attributes on it according to the options (see [here](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb#L104) and [here](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb#L129) in the source code). You have properly configured Rails that you want to verify peer certificates but **you have not configured a certificate store to verify peers against**.

This can be done using the **`ca_file` or `ca_path` options**, so the following Rails configuration should work for you:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_setting = {
    ...
    ssl: true
    enable_starttls_auto: false,
    openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER,
    ca_file: "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",
    ...
}
```

*I have no idea why this is not properly documented in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration)...*

Comment: Ill try it out when at a computer later, nice explanation. Does this apply to all TLS in Ruby/Rails applications? I have some uses of Net::HTTP with use_ssl=true as well, and had assumed those also verified

Comment: I wouldn't say it applies to all SSL requests in Ruby. Sometimes the verification is set (usually using the `set_params` method), sometimes not, as in SMTP. So I guess it's different in each case in general.

Comment: `I have no idea why this is not properly documented` - this

Answer (score 0):

This Rails configuration works for me (using Ruby 2.2.2 and Rails 5):

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_setting = {
  ...
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER,
  openssl_verify_depth: 3,  # if your CA is a sub signer
  ca_file: "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",
  ...
}
```