# Easy Redmine SMTP configuration error: An error occurred while sending mail (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed)

Tags: ruby, email, smtp, certificate, redmine

I have following smtp configuration (/redmine_path/config/configuration.yml)

```
default:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: mail.example.com
      port: 465
      authentication: :plain
      domain: mail.example.com
      user_name: "redmine@example.com"
      password: "xxxxxxxx"
      tls: true
      enable_starttls_auto: false
      openssl_verify_mode: 'peer'
```

You would expect that this is a correct configuration for TLS/SMTP mail server configuration.

But when you try to send test email. You get the following error:
**An error occurred while sending mail (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Correct configuration requires additional parameter (Tested on Debian):

```
  ca_file: "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

or

```
  ca_path: "/etc/ssl/certs/"
```

After that change Redmine correctly finds CA Root Certificates.

#### Fully working configuration:

```
default:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: mail.example.com
      port: 465
      authentication: :plain
      domain: mail.example.com
      user_name: "redmine@example.com"
      password: "xxxxxxxx"
      tls: true
      enable_starttls_auto: false
      openssl_verify_mode: 'peer'
      ca_file: "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
```

### Also make sure you have updated ca-certificates:

Exchange "package-manager" for yum, apt-get or zypper

```
<package-manager> install ca-certificates
```

I wonder how many people gave up and just set openssl_verify_mode to 'none'. Scary to think about with possible man-in-the-middle attack.

**More information about Ruby ActionMailer::Base configuration**: [ActionMailer SMTP "certificate verify failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518887/actionmailer-smtp-certificate-verify-failed)