# ActionMailer: Using multiple self-signed certificates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, actionmailer

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518887/actionmailer-smtp-certificate-verify-failed) about how to use a self-signed certificate with ActionMailer on stackoverflow.
According to an answer, it can be done with the code below.

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_setting = {
    ...
    ssl: true
    enable_starttls_auto: false,
    openssl_verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER,
    ca_file: "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",
    ...
}
```

As you can see, a ca_file can be specified with this line `ca_file: "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"`.

Though the answer is really concise and helped me figure out how to send emails with a self-signed certificate using ActionMailer, it still left me the two following questions.

1) Is it possible to set more than one ,in my case three, different self-signed certificates? If the answer is yes, how?

2) Is it possible to use a `.der` file as a self-signed certificate instead of a `.crt` file? or Should I always convert a `.der` file into a `.crt` file when I use it as a self-signed certificate?

I couldn't find much information regarding this matter, I would appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is it possible to set more than one ,in my case three, different self-signed certificates? If the answer is yes, how?

The `ca_file` can contain multiple CA certificates in PEM format. Just put them one after each other into the file, i.e. `cat cert1.pem cert2.pem > ca.pem`. Make sure that each of the input files has a line end at the end though.

> 2) Is it possible to use a .der file as a self-signed certificate instead of a .crt file? or Should I always convert a .der file into a .crt file when I use it as a self-signed certificate?

DER and PEM are both essentially the same data only with a different encoding (binary vs. base64 with some ASCII envelope) and it is easy to convert one into the other. `ca_file` expects a list of PEM, not DER.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!! 

`ca_file expects a list of PEM, not DER.`

Does that mean I can list PEM files like the code below???
`ca_file: "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificate1.crt", "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificate2.crt"`

Comment: @K-Sato: No, I mean that you can put all the PEM after each other in the same file as I've showed in my answer: `cat cert1.pem cert2.pem > ca.pem`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your help !!